# SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

Good afternoon,

I am developing a script in python and while I am trying to compile it from the terminator/terminal i always get this error, but I cannot understand where is the syntax error?

File "_case1.py", line 128

```
print ('########################')
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Then I just change the position of the sentence and what I get is..

```
print '########################'
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the previous line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the code before the `print` line for errors. This can be caused by an error in a previous line; for example:

```
def x():
    y = [
    print "hello"
x()
```

This produces the following error:

```
  File "E:\Python\test.py", line 14
    print "hello"
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When clearly the error is in the line before it, `y = [`. It's tough to debug without more code, but if you have some brackets missing before the print line or something similar it can cause such an error.